# How can I imitate medfilt2 of Matlab with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I have an imaging application written in Matlab and need to convert it into C++ app with OpenCV. But I can't seem to find an easy way to imitate medfilt2 with OpenCV.

I tried MedianBlur but it didn't produce the same result. Could anybody give me any clue for this task?

Comment: In what way does `medfilt2` differ from `cv::medianBlur`?

Comment: @Georg, the only way I can see, is that Matlab lets you specify "Each output pixel contains the median value in the m-by-n neighborhood around the corresponding pixel", and `cv::medianBlur` uses a `ksize*ksize` aperature.  Not sure the generic `m*n` aperature is needed by `medfilt2` provides that option.

Comment: @HerrvonWurst medfilt2 can take an even size window, but medianBlur takes only an odd size window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear to me that this [link](http://www.librow.com/articles/article-1/appendix-a-2) should have what you need.
However, looks like you'll have to make a minor modification if you want to specify the `n` by `m` window.

```
     //   Pick up window elements
     int k = 0;
     // Original: element window[9];
     element window[n_win*m_win];
     for (int j = m_win - 1; j < m_win; ++j)
        for (int i = n_win - 1; i < n_win; ++i)
           window[k++] = image[j * N + i];
     //   Order elements (only half of them)
     // make sure (n_win*m_win)/2 is odd :-)
     for (int j = 0; j < (n_win*m_win)/2; ++j)
     {
        //   Find position of minimum element
        int min = j;
        for (int l = j + 1; l < n_win*m_win; ++l)
        if (window[l] < window[min])
           min = l;
        //   Put found minimum element in its place
        const element temp = window[j];
        window[j] = window[min];
        window[min] = temp;
     }
     //   Get result - the middle element
     result[(m - 1) * (N - 2) + n - 1] = window[4];
```